# .aspx cause redirect but not other extensions

Tags: asp.net, iis, integrated

im using asp.net 4.0 integrated mode and im having problems with error redirection. Im trying to redirect 404 errors to another page.

"www.easycomputerformat.com/test.aspx" successfully redirects to 404Error.aspx

but

"www.easycomputerformat.com/test" doesnt.

Doesnt integrated pipeline mean all requrest go throu asp.net?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set routing configuration before do this?

Comment: Is this an IIS option? I have only done custom errors in web.config

Comment: Which version of IIS? (Just to be 100%)

Comment: My hosting company uses IIS 7

Comment: What is shown when you write */test ?

Comment: Just the generic error page, you can try it yourself